# java script image rollover issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment due tomorrow.. I'm stuck on on particular requirement. I need to do a java script image rollover I'm my HTML using a separate Script page. and then linking the page to the Html Head tag.

Here is my java script page than I'm using the functions in the tags and its still not calling it over.. are there any suggestions?

This is the javascript file:

```
// Pre load images for rollover
function imgOver() 
{
    document.getElementById('logo').src="images/logo1.jpeg"; 
}

function imgOut() 
{
    document.getElementById('logo').src="images/logo.jpeg"; 
}

onclick=”window.print( ); return false;”
```

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="author" content="Teancum Clark" />
        <meta name="class" content="INFO 2450 - Web Content Design" />
        <meta name="section" content="001" />
        <meta name="project" content="expresswebpractice2a" />
        <meta name="due_date" content="11/07/2012" />
        <meta name="instructor" content="Kim Bartholomew" />
        <meta name="description" content="Description of the project here..." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="expweb2a" />
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />




            <script type="text/javascript" src="MyScript.js"></script>



    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="fl" id="wrapper">
            <div class="fl" id="content">
                <div class="fl" id="header">
                    <div class="fl" id="leftImage">
                        <a href="#" onmouseover="imgOver();" onmouseout="imgOut()">
                        <img id="logo" alt="logo" height="150" src="images/logo1.jpeg" width="110" />
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="fl" id="rightImage">
                        <img class="rightImage"src="Images/banner.png" alt="Pets R Us banner"/>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--header-->

                <div class="fl" id="left">
                    <a class="buttons fl" href="index.htm">Home</a>
                    <a class="buttons fl" href="AboutUs.htm">About</a>
                    <a class="buttons fl" href="Tributes.htm">Tributes</a>
                </div><!--left-->


                <div class="fl" id="right">
                    right
                </div><!--right-->

                <div class="fl" id="footer">
                    The great Pets R Us staff came and picked her up two hours later and I didn't even have to worry about feeding or watering "Sophie".
                    We now have a regular appointment every Saturday...
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    Yours, 
                    <br/>
                    Jewel Anderson, 
                    <br/>
                    Centerville, UT
                    <br/>
                    <a class="buttons fl" href="Tribute.htm">Read More?</a>     

                        <img class="center" src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" height="31" width="88" />
                </div><!--footer-->

            <br style="clear:both; font-size:1px;" />
            </div><!--content-->
        </div><!--wrapper-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick=”window.print( ); return false;”
```

that line is illegal, and causing your script file to be ignored, remove that and your mouseover/out will begin to work

Comment: The line returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: yeah that was a print button I'm having trouble with as well... but i removed it and the image rollover is still not working still not working... :(

Comment: are both images in the right spot?  The code looks good otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
`onclick=”window.print( ); return false;”`

You're using *fancy quotes* which will cause a mess.

Try this:
`onclick="window.print( ); return false;";`

Comment: Though I'm not really sure what that code is supposed to be doing in the first place...